# How to compare forEach value with selected dropdown value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var externalData = [{ "sedesc": "TAX 1040-2000" },
                    { "sedesc": "TAX 1040-2005" }
                   ];
      var extData;      
   externalData.forEach(function (data) {
      console.log(data.sedesc)
      extData = data.sedesc
   })
onApprove: function(){
if ($('#extservicecode option:selected').text() === extData ) {
       alertify.error("Duplicates are not allowed");                              
   }
}}
```

This is my jquery code. I have a dropdown `($('#extservicecode option:selected').text())` in which if I select any of the above value of `"data.sedesc"` it should display an error message . I need to compare the selected value with the value already present.

**UPDATE**

```
externalData.forEach(function (data) {
                console.log(data.Scdesc)
                duplicatedData = data.Scdesc
            })
if ($('#extservicecode option:selected').text() === duplicatedData) {
        alertify.error("Duplicates are not allowed");                              
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value on change and then compare the selected value with the values in your array.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const value = $('#extservicecode option:selected').text();

  externalData.forEach(function (data) {
      if (value === data) {
        // duplicate value found
      }
  });
});
```

According to your `onApprove` method

```
onApprove: function(){
  // Get the dropdown value
  const duplicateData = null;
  const value = $('#extservicecode option:selected').text();

  // iterate over external data
  externalData.forEach(function (data) {
    // check if dropdown value has one of the duplicate value
    if (value === data) {
      duplicateData = data;
      // duplicate value found
     }
  });

  // duplicateData can be used here
  // dropdown value is valid
}
```

Comment: i want to compare this on button click not on dropdown value  change

Comment: @chethu updated code block for button click event now.

Comment: check now onApprove function i had written

Comment: @chethu updated answer. you are missing the point. your method must get the value from dropdown and then be compared 1 by 1 from each value in the duplicate data array. if there is no match found then your dropdown value is valid else its invalid.

Comment: how to access data value outside forEach ??

Comment: you can't directly. you would have to create another variable for that @chethu

Comment: how to do that i tried creating  new variable and used it outside of it as shown in question its not working

Comment: it is still accepting value not showing error message see my updated question i need to use like that

Comment: @chethu you aren't using it in the right way. You have to move ```externalData.forEach``` inside of ```onApprove``` method

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to the `change` event of the dropdown and put that if statement in the event handler.

```
// simplify the check by making an array of strings to match against
var sedescList = externalData.map(function(item) {
  return item.sedesc;
}

$('#extservicecode').change(function() {                   //set change handler for select element
  $('#extservicecode option:selected').each(function() {   //check each selected option
    if (sedescList.includes($(this).text())) {             //check if text is one of the elements of sedescList
      alertify.error("Duplicates are not allowed");                              
    }
  }    
}
```